# How to retrieve iTunes preferences programmatically to find audio libraries?

Tags: cocoa, macos, audio, itunes

I'm creating an application on the Mac in Cocoa that plays audio. I think the best place for my application to search for audio files on a user's computer is to get the directory path(s) from iTunes. How would I retrieve the directory paths(s) from iTunes? Would this be in some sort of preference setting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just for those who will encounter this problem in the future, I've documented the approach that I used below.

I decided not to use the Karelia framework because I don't need all the bells and whistles. I just need to locate the iTunes library and display a list of songs.

I went through the Karelia framework and it appears that they locate the iTunes library via the user defaults as shown below.

```
+ (NSArray*) parserInstancesForMediaType:(NSString*)inMediaType
{
    NSMutableArray* parserInstances = [NSMutableArray array];

    if ([self isInstalled])
    {
        CFArrayRef recentLibraries = CFPreferencesCopyAppValue((CFStringRef)@"iTunesRecentDatabases",(CFStringRef)@"com.apple.iApps");
        NSArray* libraries = (NSArray*)recentLibraries;

        for (NSString* library in libraries)
        {
            NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:library];
            NSString* path = [url path];
            BOOL changed;
            (void) [[NSFileManager imb_threadSafeManager] imb_fileExistsAtPath:&path wasChanged:&changed];

            NSString *libraryPath = [path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];   // folder containing .xml file
            [IMBConfig registerLibraryPath:libraryPath];

            IMBiTunesParser* parser = [[[self class] alloc] initWithMediaType:inMediaType];
            parser.mediaSource = path;
            parser.shouldDisplayLibraryName = libraries.count > 1;
            [parserInstances addObject:parser];
            [parser release];
        }

        if (recentLibraries) CFRelease(recentLibraries);
    }

    return parserInstances;
}
```

Using the above approach, you can locate all iTunes libraries with the following code.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *userPref = [userDefaults persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.iApps"];

NSArray *recentDatabases = [userPref objectForKey:@"iTunesRecentDatabases"];

for (NSString *key in recentDatabases)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", key);
}
```

Also if you inspect the user defaults iApps dictionary you can use these other keys to get info for other applications

```
iMovie
iPhotoAutoImportPath
iPhotoRecentDatabases
iTunesRecentDatabases
iTunesRecentDatabasePaths
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: As others have pointed out, the approach below doesn't address the case that the iTunes library may not be in a user's home folder. See [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703945/how-to-retrieve-itunes-preferences-programmatically-to-find-audio-libraries/4708123#4708123) for a better solution. Finding the user's music folder may still be somewhat useful for finding a standard (though not the only) location of non-iTunes audio files (e.g. as the default folder for an open panel).

*Original answer*:

You could locate the user's Music folder via

```
NSString *musicPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSMusicDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

This will normally have an iTunes subdirectory that contains the file "iTunes Music Library.xml" which contains most metadata of the user's iTunes library. Don't try to write to it though - iTunes only creates this file so that other apps can access it, but doesn't use it internally otherwise.

Comment: Perfect. That's what I'll use.

Comment: @omz, @David: The iTunes library is not necessarily in the Music folder in the Home folder. This is a preference in iTunes; for those of us who've changed it (e.g., to a much larger external drive), an app that assumes we haven't will not work.

Comment: Right. Do you know what iTunes' defaults key is for that?

Comment: Nope. You can use the `strings` command to find it, but I still recommend using iMedia Browser or Scripting Bridge instead.

Comment: There's a prefs file named com.apple.iApps.plist where both iPhoto and iTunes store a reference to the XML file for the most recently accessed library. You can use -[NSUserDefaults persistentDomainForName:] to get that data, and that will point you to the user's iTunes library XML file.

Comment: @Peter, thanks for the tip, I've revised the method by locating the library through the user defaults as suggested by @Brian. Thanks Brian.

Comment: I've edited my answer to point to yours, you should probably mark your own answer as accepted, so that it shows up at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Use [the Scripting Bridge](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/) to talk to iTunes. You can ask iTunes about the user's library and every track in it; file tracks will freely tell you where they are in the file-system.

Alternatively, embed Karelia Software's [iMedia Browser](http://www.karelia.com/imedia/) framework, which will talk to iTunes for you.

You probably should also be able to open audio files that the user drops on your app or assigns to it in Finder's Get Info and opens. Consider [making your application document-based](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Documents.html); alternatively, implement [the right application delegate method](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSApplicationDelegate/application%3aopenFiles%3a) and declare [the right Info.plist properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-101685).

Comment: Use iMedia Browser, even if you just copy out the code that locates the library

Comment: I've briefly skimmed through the Karelia framework and it appears that they obtain the user's iTunes library using the user defaults.