# How to retrieve iTunes path from Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm aware of this question [How to retrieve iTunes preferences programmatically to find audio libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703945/how-to-retrieve-itunes-preferences-programmatically-to-find-audio-libraries) .

But I need to retrieve path for iTunes like - **/Users/user/Music/iTunes** , and also Media folder of iTunes  **/Users/user/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media**

I don't want to hard-code that paths. So how can I retrieve them?

Thanks!

P.S. I need this for MAC OS X 10.5,10.6,10.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way is to check in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iApps.plist` which lists the most recently used iTunes library XML path and URL under the keys `iTunesRecentDatabasePaths` and `iTunesRecentDatabases` respectively. I believe that has been used since at least 10.3 Panther.

Comment: Thanks,But I'm new in Cocoa, and have no idea, how to parste that value to STring

Comment: Read David's comment in the question you referenced, it contains everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

Load the `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.itunes.plist` into an NSDictionary and get the value for the "alis:11345:Music Folder Location" key. The NSData object you get back is a file alias.

Comment: Aliases and bookmarks are two different things. If the value is alias data (and, judging by the key, I suspect it is), the bookmark methods will not work with it.

Comment: Ah. Good to know. I removed the suggestion.

Comment: You're still saying “file alias ("bookmark data")”, though. An alias is not bookmark data, nor vice versa. Same goal, but different and mutually incompatible ways of achieving it. To resolve an alias, you must use the Alias Manager.